# Fortran Module Version Fatal Error

Tags: module, fortran, fortran95

I have a very scary error on Fortran 95:

```
Fatal Error: While reading module 'list5.mod' found module version 0, expected 6
```

I have included the main structure of my module. I highly doubt it has anything to do with the substance inside my module since it has given me error messages on those and I have been able to fix them which means it is able to go through my module fine it is just something small related to the way I use the module. Perhaps?

```
    MODULE list5
    IMPLICIT NONE

    CONTAINS

----

END MODULE
```

The main program is structured something like this:

```
    PROGRAM mainlist
    USE list5
IMPLICIT NONE

    !Variable Declaration
    INTEGER:: opt
    INTEGER, PARAMETER:: maxitems=50
    INTEGER:: size=0
    CHARACTER(20):: itemarray(50)
    INTEGER:: quantityarray(50)
    INTEGER:: totalquantity, i=0
    REAL:: totalprice=0, pricearray(50)=0

    CHARACTER(20), DIMENSION(:)::Item
    CHARACTER(20):: ItemSought
    LOGICAL:: Found
    INTEGER:: Location

    INTEGER:: NumItems=0, SmallestItem=0

!Select statement for the menu

DO
opt=choices()
SELECT CASE (opt)
    CASE(1)
        size=size+1
        CALL getItemData(itemarray,pricearray,quantityarray)
    CASE(2)
        CALL getFileItems(size,itemarray,pricearray,quantityarray)
    CASE(3)
        CALL pickItemRandomly (size)
    CASE(4)
        CALL calcListTotals
(pricearray,quantityarray,totalprice,totalquantity)
        CALL printList(size,itemarray,pricearray,quantityarray,totalprice, totalquantity)
    CASE(5)
        CALL sortByItem(itemarray, pricearray, quantityarray)
    CASE(6)
        CALL sortByPrice(itemarray, pricearray, quantityarray)
    CASE(7)
        CALL writeListtoFile(size,itemarray, pricearray, quantityarray)

    CASE(8)
        CALL search(itemarray, ItemSought, Found, Location)
    CASE(9)
        STOP
END SELECT
END DO



END PROGRAM
```

Any suggestions at all?? I really need to solve this so any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!!

Comment: I cannot reproduce it from given data, naturally, but from what I googled, it seems that this error occurs when different versions of compilers are used (btw, what compiler are you using, g95?). Some links which may have some relevance. http://forum.wrfforum.com/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=1205 http://www.docstoc.com/docs/37887247/Athena-Knowledge-Base

Comment: May have to scroll down a bit through the document in the second one.

Comment: @Rook yeah I'm using g95

Comment: @EuropaDust - Okey, put it onto some paste site (https://gist.github.com/) - but try Jonathan's suggestion first.

Comment: @Rook I tried Jonathon's suggestion, but I don't know if it will allow me to run the program later or not. Do you know? I'm putting on the paste site you provided. What do I do next? Thanks.

Comment: @EuropaDust - You need to provide the link to where you placed it. For example, I've written some text, clicked on "create public gist" and after that I've gotten a link: https://gist.github.com/925181 Also, not for this one, but for some of the other questions you've posted; it would be a good idea (by default) to always put in your compiler and copy paste the errors you got. If for no other reasons,  but to avoid giving people reasons to post questions like "what compiler are you using"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Rook says, the issue is with compiler versions; somehow the .mod file from by compiling list5 the first time around was generated by an older compiler.   Clear out all your .o and .mod files, and try again, first compiling list5.f90 (or whatever the file containing module list5 is) and then compiling the main program.

Comment: When I compile the module alone, the error message goes away. But will the program still be able to run if compiled separately from the module? ie: will the error message reappear when I'm ready to run the program like normal?? thanks!

Comment: so I tried to continue to compile separately as you suggested but and initially the error went away as I say in my previous comment, but now I have a completely weird error that I have never seen in my life. It is a very long error message too.

Comment: Yes, the modules and programs don't have to be compiled at the same time.  They have to be compiled in a suitable order and with the same compiler.   So if a program or procedures uses a module, you need to compile the module first.   Circular dependencies are not allowed!   You can compile in separate steps, or with one compile command, but in either case the order of the files matters.  If you show us your new error, maybe we can help....

Comment: but if the program and its module only compile separately, how is it supposed to run? the new error message occurs b/c i'm calling something from my module and b/c my module isn't being compiled at the same time, the compiler treats it like junk, i think.

Comment: When you compile (eg, g95 -c list5.f90) the source code for the module, you will get a "list5.mod" and a "list5.o".   The object (.o) file contains the compiled (but not linked) code; the .mod file is like a .h file or something; it contains very detailed type information which is needed for _compilation_, not for linking.   As MSB says, compile your module source first, then the main body of your program, then link them together (g95 -o mainlist mainlist.o list5.o).   You don't need the .mod for linking, only for compiling.

Comment: unfortunately it is still not working for me. I can't get the two to link.

Comment: Copy-and-paste your build procedure and the resulting errors.

Comment: After playing around with it for a few hours, I finally got it to work. I don't remember what I did, but it works now. Thanks all for your patience.